# TextView.setWidth not working if no text

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I am dynamically adding TextViews to a LinearLayout, setting their layout parameters appropriately. The LinearLayout is inside a custom scrollview.

I don't have the text for each TextView immediately, so some of them get set at different times, and some of them never get set. I'd like them all to be the same width, so I have to wait until `onLayout` to update their width (each textview should be 1/2 the width of the scrollview).

My problem: Only the TextViews with text are appearing. If text is null or empty, they just don't display, even though I am setting their width in `onLayout`.

Add the TextViews:

```
//This happens when scrollView is created. We don't have the scrollview's width yet
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);

/**add layout rules omitted **/

linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Then set their width:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    int width = getWidth();
    int totalWidth = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TextView textView = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        //Each textView will be 1/2 the width of the scrollview
        textView.getLayoutParams().width = width / 2;//Try setting params width
        textView.setWidth(width / 2);//Try directly setting width
        totalWidth += width / 2;
    }
    linearLayout.getLayoutParams().width = totalWidth;
    linearLayout.setMinimumWidth(totalWidth);
    linearLayout.requestLayout();
```

Note I tried setting their width 2 different ways above, but nothing works. Do TextViews not have a width if they have no text?

Comment: What is field? I don't see it declared anywhere.

Comment: It's textView, sorryI just updated it

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the LinearLayout before the child TextViews.

Calculate the total width first, apply it to the parent Layout, then apply half widths to each TextView.

I don't see `currentWidth` either, so I am not adding complete code myself.

**EDIT**:

```
linearLayout.getLayoutParams().width = totalWidth = width * 0.5 * linearLayout.getChildCount();
linearLayout.setMinimumWidth(totalWidth);

for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    TextView textView = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
    textView.setText(""); // I don't think this is needed, but you CAN add this too
    //Each textView will be 1/2 the width of the scrollview
    textView.getLayoutParams().width = width / 2;//Try setting params width
    textView.setWidth(width / 2);//Try directly setting width
}


linearLayout.requestLayout();
```

Comment: What do you mean "apply it to the parent layout"?

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. Same problem as before.

Comment: Can you log or see if all the parent layouts, ie the linear layout and above have some width greater than the width you're trying to set?

Comment: Yeah I'm logging and all the widths are correct, they just don't render for some reason.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to actually being a problem with the linearLayout. For some reason, its width doesn't render correctly, even though I set it. Logging shows that it's set to the correct value. Makes no sense.